# tf2: I can broadcast transfroms but I cannot listen to them. I keep getting [ERROR] : Lookup would require extrapolation

Tags: ros, python, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am trying to do a simple broadcast/listen of tf2 where I broadcast a frame and then listen to it and transform a point in that frame. However, the broadcasting script is working as intended but I cannot listen to it  and I keep getting:

```
[ERROR] [1607460129.073986]: Lookup would require extrapolation 0.009213686s into the past.  Requested time 1607460126.067262173 but the earliest data is at time 1607460126.076475859, when looking up transform from frame [base_laser] to frame [base_link]
```

Here are the two scripts:

Broadcaster:

```
import rospy
import tf2_ros
import geometry_msgs.msg
from tf.transformations import *
import tf_conversions


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('tf2_turtle_broadcaster')
    rate = rospy.Rate(100)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        broadcaster = tf2_ros.TransformBroadcaster()

        t = geometry_msgs.msg.TransformStamped()
        t.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        t.header.frame_id = "base_link"
        t.child_frame_id = "base_laser"
        t.transform.rotation = geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1)
        t.transform.translation = geometry_msgs.msg.Vector3(0.1, 0, 0.2)

        broadcaster.sendTransform(t)
        rate.sleep()
```

Listener:

```
import rospy

import tf2_ros
import geometry_msgs.msg
from tf2_geometry_msgs import PointStamped

from tf.transformations import *

if __name__ == "__main__":

    rospy.init_node('robot_tf_listener')

    laser_point = PointStamped()
    laser_point.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    laser_point.header.frame_id = "base_laser"
    laser_point.point.x = 1
    laser_point.point.y = 0.2
    laser_point.point.z = 0

    tfBuffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
    listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tfBuffer)

    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            rospy.loginfo('1')
            tran = tfBuffer.transform(laser_point, "base_link", timeout=rospy.Duration(3))
            rospy.loginfo('2')

        except Exception as e:
            rospy.logerr(e)

        rate.sleep()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367262/tf2:-i-can-broadcast-transfroms-but-i-cannot-listen-to-them.-i-keep-getting-%5Berror%5D-:-lookup-would-require-extrapolation/) by [Forenkazan](https://answers.ros.org/users/64940/forenkazan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-08**:
Are you using two different machines? If so, this may have to do with the machines not having their clocks synced. See the [network setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Timing_issues.2C_TF_complaining_about_extrapolation_into_the_future.3F) on the wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `Time(0)` instead of `Time.now()`. For more detail, check out the following: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20(Python)

---

Originally posted by [apawlica](https://answers.ros.org/users/64517/apawlica/) with karma: 46 on 2020-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-08**:
The op is using `tf2` and the tutorial that you're linking to is the deprecated `tf` package.

**Comment by [apawlica](https://answers.ros.org/users/64517/apawlica/) on 2020-12-08**:
Wouldn't the relevant bit (using Time(0) instead of Time.now()) still be applicable, as it's a timing issue and not unique to tf2?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-08**:
See [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/205500/tf-error-lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-past/?answer=205567#post-id-205567)